# How to export format settings (label, weight, etc) for body field, image field, and tags field

Tags: entities, features, display-suite, importing-exporting

I'm trying to export my layout settings that I did in Display Suite for my article content type full content view. All my settings for various fields (label and order) do take except the image, body, and tag fields. For example I change the label for the body field to hidden, export, and clear my db but when I go back to look it shows it as 'above'. I've tried to go into the exported code for display suite itself and insert in a 'label' => 'hidden' into the array also but that doesn't work either.

The order issue is where the tags field always show up before the body field. I've even checked the ds_layout_settings_info() function and the weight numbering of the array looks correct.

Why is it that only those three fields won't export correctly? Someone said that those specific settings are in core/field api fields but I can't find what to export in Features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what I was doing wrong. Since I was working with Features for some reason the Article Content Type originally got exported out into another module and was clashing with mine.